# Возможно ли в golang использовать методы класса из Windows.Devices.WiFi.dll

Tags: windows, golang, dll, wifi

В [примере](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/?GOOS=windows#example_LoadLibrary)
 в документации для пакета syscall используется функция [GetVersion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversion) из kernel32.dll.

Возможно ли использовать методы класса из библиотеки [Windows.Devices.WiFi.dll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi) таким же образом?
Например класс [WiFiAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter) имеет метод [FindAllAdaptersAsync()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter.findalladaptersasync).

```c
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    h, err := syscall.LoadLibrary("Windows.Devices.WiFi.dll")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("LoadLibrary: %v\n", err)
    }
    defer syscall.FreeLibrary(h)

    proc, err := syscall.GetProcAddress(h, "WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdaptersAsync")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("GetProcAddress: %v\n", err)
    }
    r, _, _ := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(proc), 0, 0, 0, 0)
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

Вывод:

```
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: kernel32.dll  это машинный код, а Windows.Devices.WiFi это imho .NET, то есть код для виртуальной машины. Вы быстрее найдёте решение это проблемы для C, то есть как использовать в native-C .NET dll, ну и там может сообразите, как применить это для golang

Comment: @PavelGridin это не .NET, это UWP/Windows Runtime. Ничего связанного с виртуальной машиной там нет (наоборот, даже .NET-приложения для UWP предкомпилируются в машинный код).

Comment: Проще будет написать обертку на С++ и затем уже вызывать свою функцию.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, виноват, невнимательно прочитал справочник

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это возможно. Все UWP API опираются на COM и соответственно могут напрямую использоваться из С и языков, поддерживающих вызовы С, в т.ч. go. Однако для этого придется изрядно постараться. Последовательность действий примерно такая:

1. Инициализиация UWP вызовом `RoInitialize`
2. Получить ссылку на рантайм имя класса `L"Windows.Devices.WiFi.WiFiAdapter"` вызовом `WindowsCreateStringReference`
3. Создать экземпляр класса и получить указатель на предоставляемый им интерфейс `IInspectable` вызовом `RoActivateInstance`
4. Получить указатель на интерфейс `IWiFiAdapterStatics` вызовом виртуального метода `QueryInterface` у `IInspectable`
5. Начать асинхронную операцию получения статистики вызовом виртуального метода `FindAllAdaptersAsync` `IWiFiAdapterStatics`

Информацию об именах рантайм классов и реализуемых ими интерфейсах можно подчерпнуть из idl файлов идущих в Windows SDK.